# Accessing scope of test during parallel execution on Specflow and Nunit

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow, parallel-testing

I implemented a test framework using NUnit, with Parallelism on Child level - ParallelScope.Children without issue. I made a nested class within the textFixture so that each [Test] has its own scope and would not overlap on each other.

Now, I have to integrate Specflow into the above test. I used "dependency injection" to share some state as guided and everything runs fine without issue, without Parallelism

The issue arise when i tried to run in Parallel at Fixture level for Specflow - this means 1 test from this feature runs in parallel with another test in another feature.

*Here are my configurations*:
NUnit 3.11
Specflow 2.41 (I got some issue with Specflow 3 so i used 2.41)
Net 4.6.1
NUnit Test Adapter 3

**Hooks:**

```
private static TestScopeContext _testScope;
private readonly IObjectContainer _objectContainer;

public Hooks(IObjectContainer objectContainer)
{
     _objectContainer = objectContainer;
}

[BeforeTestRun]
public static void SetUpTestScope()
{
     _testScope = new TestScopeContext();
}

[BeforeScenario]
public void CreateScenario(FeatureContext featureContext, ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
{
     _objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<TestScopeContext>(_testScope);
     //some codes that need access to feature context, scenario context. Not sure if this is the correct way
}
```

**TestScopeContext.cs**

```
public class TestScopeContext:IDisposable
{
   public string value;
   //other codes
}
```

**Binding steps**

FileA.cs

```
[Binding]
    public class FileProcessingTestSteps
    {
        private readonly TestScopeContext _testScope;
        private readonly ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;

        public FileProcessingTestSteps(
            TestScopeContext testScope,
            ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
        {
            _testScope = testScope;
            _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
        }


        [When(@"The user drops the file to (.*) UNC path")]
        public void WhenTheUserDropsTheFileToUNCPath(string client)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title);
            Console.WriteLine(_testScope.value);  //issue at this line          
        }
}
```

FileB.cs

```
[Binding]
    public class CitiTestStepsDefinition
    {
        private readonly TestScopeContext _testScope;
        private readonly ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;

        public CitiTestStepsDefinition(
            TestScopeContext testScope,
            ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
        {
            _testScope = testScope;
            _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
        }

        [Given(@"The user modifies the File (.*)")]
        public void GivenTheUserModifiesTheFile(string text)
        {            
            _testScope.value= _scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title;           
        }
    }
```

Question 1:

Given I have 2 tests - Test1, Test2.

The `Console.WriteLine(_testScope.value);` when running will give either Test1 for both tests, or Test2 depends which value is assigned last.

Is this testScope only one instance, regardless of how many workers I defined.

Question 2:
I tried to remove this code `_objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<TestScopeContext>(_testScope);`

Then the scope of test runs correctly, _testScope.value returns **Test1** for this scenario, and **Test2** for another scenario.

I thought that the `RegisterInstanceAs` is used so that the "TestScope" state can be shared among binding steps. Is there something wrong with my configurations?

If it is not clear, please let me know i can try to duplicate my working project and attach code here

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake declaring TestScopeContext _testScope as static. Remove the static keyword, move the logic to create a new TestScopeContext instance to [BeforeScenario] fix this issue.